# RNCalendarEvents.saveEvent() issues Error: No calendar has been set

Tags: javascript, react-native

My `react-native-calendar-events` code is throwing an error, the error is saying `No calendar has been set`, but I don't know why this is happening. The same code on the legacy version of my app works on the same devices.

```
export async function createCalendarEvent(event) {
  const status = await RNCalendarEvents.authorizationStatus();
  console.log(status);
  if (status === "authorized" || status === "undetermined") {
    addToCalendar(event);
  } else {
    RNCalendarEvents.authorizeEventStore()
      .then(auth => {
        // handle status
        if (auth === "authorized" || auth === "undetermined") {
          addToCalendar(event);
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        alert("This app needs calendar access");
      });
  }
}

async function addToCalendar(event) {
  try {
    const startDate =
      Platform.OS === "ios"
        ? format(parse(event.StartDateLocal))
        : parse(event.StartDateLocal);
    const endDate =
      Platform.OS === "ios"
        ? format(parse(event.EndDateLocal))
        : parse(event.EndDateLocal);
    const allEvents = await RNCalendarEvents.fetchAllEvents(startDate, endDate);

    const calendarEvent = allEvents.find(e => e.title === event.Title);
    if (calendarEvent) {
      alert("You have already added this event to your calendar.");
    } else {
      const title = event.Title;

      const {
        Location: {
          AddressLine1: address,
          City: city,
          StateAbbreviation: state,
          PostalCode: zip
        }
      } = event;

      const location = `${address}, ${city}, ${state}, ${zip}`;

      const settings = {
        location,
        startDate,
        endDate
      };
      RNCalendarEvents.saveEvent(title, settings)
        .then(() => {
          alert("Event Saved");
        })
        .catch(rejectionReason => {
          console.log(rejectionReason);
          alert("Oops! Something has gone wrong.");
        });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert("Oops! Something has gone wrong with this request.");
  }
}
```

I recently added the Or in `status === "authorized" || status === "undetermined"`, that somehow has kept the iOS side from crashing completely when it errors out.

I thought it might be a version issue, but I went back to the version we had and I still have this issue. So the Promise is erroring out, but why?

I put together a minimally viable product like so:

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import RNCalendarEvents from "react-native-calendar-events";
import parse from "date-fns/parse";
import format from "date-fns/format";

const ComponentsScreen = () => {
  async function addToCalendar(event) {
    console.log(RNCalendarEvents);
    try {
      RNCalendarEvents.saveEvent("Title of event", {
        startDate: "2016-08-19T19:26:00.000Z",
        endDate: "2017-08-19T19:26:00.000Z"
      })
        .then(() => {
          alert("Event Saved");
        })
        .catch(rejectionReason => {
          console.log(rejectionReason);
          alert("Oops! Something has gone wrong.");
        });
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e.message);
    }
```

And the `RNCalendarEvents` method of `saveEvent()` returns undefined even though the `RNCalendarEvents` I console log, returns all the methods available to this API. I thought this would suggest a linking issue, but it should be autolinking and at any rate I tried `react-native link` and still getting undefined on its methods.

I just noticed through my debugging process that `react-native-calendar-events` is still using `index.ios.js`. Could that be why I am getting back the methods for the `RNCalendarEvents` API, but when I try to implement them I get back `undefined`.

**UPDATE:**

I added the following inside of `MainActivity.java`:

```
package com.nfibengage;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "NFIBEngage";
    }

    /*
     * this is for https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SplashScreen.show(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionResult(int RequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
      super.onRequestPermissionResult(RequestCode, permissions, grantResults);
      CalendarEventsPackage.onRequestPermissionResult(RequestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

And I am still getting the same error message of `No calendar has been set`.

So I thought perhahs I needed to add the import: `import com.calendarevents.CalendarEventsPackage;`. After I added it to `MainActivity.java` and ran Android emulator again, on build I got the following errors:

> error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>   error: cannot find symbol method
>   onRequestPermissionResult(int,String[],int[]) error: cannot find
>   symbol method onRequestPermissionResult(int,String[],int[])

I was able to resolve the first error: `error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype` by simply removing `@Override` from:

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionResult(int RequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
      super.onRequestPermissionResult(RequestCode, permissions, grantResults);
      CalendarEventsPackage.onRequestPermissionResult(RequestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

Comment: it looks like the same issue with https://github.com/wmcmahan/react-native-calendar-events/issues/52

Comment: @KaramanOkan, yes it does, with one difference, in my project I have the necessary configuration in `plist`.

Comment: i guess u are having permission issue, can you pls remove `|| status === "undetermined"` parts and retry it ?

Comment: @KaramanOkan, that makes sense, because on the Android side today, I got an Alert that read: `you don't have permissions to read an event from the users calendar`, and I don't think that alert is hard coded into this application, it may be coming from `RNCalendarEvents` proper?

Comment: @KaramanOkan, I removed `|| status === "undetermined"` and on Android, it asked for my permission to access calendar, I clicked OK and then I clicked add to calendar again and I got the `alert("Oops! Something has gone wrong.");` error.

Comment: i think so.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201343/discussion-between-daniel-and-karaman-okan).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201393/discussion-between-daniel-and-okkano).

Comment: Just want to confirm- Did you add 

     @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    CalendarEventsPackage.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    
    }

in main activity

Comment: @VinayakB, I did not.

Comment: please add. and try running on android

Comment: @VinayakB, I tried it and I am still catching here -> `.catch(rejectionReason => {
          console.log(rejectionReason);
          alert("Oops! Something has gone wrong.");`

Comment: What is the output of  `rejectionReason`

Comment: @VinayakB, `Error: No calendar has been set.`

Comment: Could please check with your calendar app. Is there any account linked with calendar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201504/discussion-between-daniel-and-vinayak-b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working on iOS only via the following refactor:

```
export async function createCalendarEvent(event) {
  const store = await RNCalendarEvents.authorizeEventStore();
  console.log(store);
  if (store === "authorize") {
    addToCalendar(event);
  } else {
    RNCalendarEvents.authorizationStatus()
      .then(auth => {
        // handle status
        if (auth === "authorized") {
          addToCalendar(event);
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        alert("This app needs calendar access");
      });
  }
}
```